# $(this.el).find() works in event handler, not in initialize function (backbone.js)

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

I am using backbone.js to create a View which contains a `Like` button. The model of this View contains the attribute `is_liked`, and if its value is `1`, then the function `setStateLike` called will change the style of the `Like` button.

**Problem:** I am not able to select the button using `this.setStateLike()` in the `initialize` function. Doing so just returns a `[]`. However, when I define `this.setStateLike` as a click event handler, selecting the button works! The stranger thing is that `this.setStateLike()` called within `initialize` is able to select `$(this.el)`, but not `$(this.el).find()`!

Any idea what has happened here and how can it be fixed? Thanks!

```
PhotoListItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'div',
    className: 'photo_box',

    events: {
        'click': 'setStateLike'
    },

    initialize: function() {
        this.setStateLike();
    },

    render: function() {
        $(this.el).html( this.template( this.model.toJSON() ) );
        return this;
    },

    setStateLike: function() {
        console.log( $(this.el).find('#like') );  // returns []
        if(this.model.get('is_liked')) {
            console.log( $(this.el) );        // returns correctly
            console.log( $(this.el).find('#like') );  // returns []
            // Change icon to Active state
            $(this.el).find('#like.photo_btn').addClass('photo_btn_active').attr('id', 'unlike');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: use `this.$el` instead of `$(this.el)` to save typing

Comment: Note that @Austin is suggesting *assigning* `this.$el` first, then using it later instead of `$(this.el)`. The best reason to do this isn't so much to save keystrokes but rather for performance: wrapping a DOM element into a jQuery object takes effort, and it's better to do it once rather than over and over.

Comment: I'm quite sure that Backbone.View defines both `this.$el` and `this.el`, without the need for assignment.

Comment: Does it mean that i need to call `$(this.el)` once to create the cache before using `this.$el`? Or is the `this.$el` already created as the cache of `$(this.el)` when the View is rendered by backbone.js?

Comment: Peripheral to the question, maybe it's just me but the whole statement `$(this.el).find('#like.photo_btn').addClass('photo_btn_active').attr('id', 'unlike');` looks all wrong. If you can identify the element by id, (and ids should be unique within the DOM) then why bother with the preamble. Either this is a repeating element and you should be using a class instead of an id, or it's unique and `$('#like.photo_btn').addClass('photo_btn_active').attr('id', 'unlike');` will correctly address it. I also question changing the element's id, which is unconventional and potentially confounding.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot I'm new to backbone.js, but I believe that using `$(this.el)` is the simplest way to limit the scope of the selector to the current View that repeats. Do you mean that instead of using `#like`, I should be using `.like` because it repeats and so if `#like` is used, it will not be unique?

Comment: Instead of changing the id from `#like` to `#unlike`, what is the conventional way of achieving the same effect?

Comment: You're already doing it by adding a class.

Comment: For a repeating partial view, something like `$(this.el).find('.photo_btn').addClass('active');` (with corresponding HTML and CSS) would make more sense but I'm not a backbone person and maybe there's something about it I don't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your script comes before the bulk of the body HTML and if the `initialize` function is being called immediately, that's your issue: the DOM isn't actually built yet, so no elements can be selected. Either run the script at the end of the `</body>`, or use [jQuery's DOM-ready handler](http://api.jquery.com/ready/).

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I moved `this.setStateLike();` to after the end of `this.render()` and it works now.